# How to Destroy an Angular application?

Tags: angular, requirejs, ngondestroy

I have an Angular application, it is an simple application with routing.
I have to include my application as a part of another website, the website load the app into a modal after loading all dependencies via RequireJS.

The opening of the app into a modal works fine.

When the modal is dismissed (and  node us dismissed with the modal) I suppose the app is destroyed.

But after modal dismiss the app seems still in memory and if I open the modal again I didn't see the application loaded (and neither catch any error).

After first usage I obtain a blank page.

So I guess that I have to force app destroy on modal dismission.

Any suggestions?

=== UPDATE ===

I tryed to follow two different ways.

1. using RequireJS undefine

   I receive an error message and it doesn't seems works
2. include main.js via Ajax request

   I didn't receive any errors but it doesn't seems works

In any case I see that Angular app seems still works, I can read the messages in console log sent by Angular controllers but the render doesn't works.

When include the main.js for the second time I read all console log message except the message in main constructor.

Comment: I believe your question requires investigation and debugging of what really happends. The thing that I think will work in most of the cases is [angular elements](https://angular.io/guide/elements). I believe that if you make your angular app an angular element it will be working fine

Comment: Why are you using requirejs with angular? Do you mean angularjs?

Comment: @Andrei after some test it seems the app still working, I can see the log to some ajax call and so on, but the render on page missing.
The tag <app-root> is append on the modal when it was opened and removed when the modal was dismissed.

Comment: @mwilson is a requirement of the site that include the app.

Comment: I still think that angular elements is the best option for you

Comment: RequireJS has method to undefine module, maybe it will be useful https://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#undef

Comment: @Zauker You should fight that one. RequireJS has no place in angular. It has it's own bundling system that is far superior than requirejs.

Comment: @DamianDziaduch I tried but I receive a Error Message. I tried  also to include main.js as ajax call, but It still doesn't work. Or better as I wrote in my update, the app seems work, I see that it perform Ajax call etc. But the render of the view is missing.

Comment: @mwilson I know, but the site offer only this kind of inclusion, before we included a similar app via iframe, but now we can't use it.